# Why does class C, which only contains member variables of type B, have sizeof(C) not equal to sizeof(B)?

Tags: c++, inheritance, memory, struct, sizeof

I have written three classes: `A`, `B`, and `C`. `A` has no member variables, `B` has an integer type member variable, and `C` has a member variable of type `B`, as shown below:

```
class A {
public:

};

class B  : public A{
private:
    int value_;
};

class C : public A{
private:
    B a;
};
```

What surprises me is that `sizeof(C)` is 8 instead of 4, as expected like `sizeof(B)`.
I had considered that this might be due to padding, but when I removed either `C` inheriting from `A` or `B` inheriting from `A`, `sizeof(C)` became 4 as expected.

I observe the same behavior on a 64-bit machine when using both GCC and Clang.

I want to know why the compiler adds an additional 4 bytes of storage overhead when compiling `C`.

Comment: `class A` has a non-zero size (probably 1) due to: _"every object must have a distinct address"_.  So `C` is composed of `A` plus `B` plus padding.

Comment: Is this the minimum sample? Does class A have virtual functions too? What is your build platform?

Comment: @Red.Wave It’s a minimum sample. The issue is that `C` has `A` as a superclass *twice*, via `B`. Otherwise you’d get `sizeof(C) == sizeof(B)`.

Comment: @user17732522 was trying not to to go into that in a comment - sorry I missed that out.

Comment: @RichardCritten Sorry, I didn't read the question properly. There are two `A` objects here and they may not share an address. So in that sense it applies. Interesting that MSVC does not behave conforming.

Comment: @RichardCritten *every object must have a distinct address* Except those which [must not](https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object#7).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two `A` subobjects in `C`: The direct `A` base class subobject and the `A` base class subobject of the `B` member subobject.

The standard requires that these two objects, because they have the same type and overlapping lifetime, and because one is not nested within the other, do not have the same address. (see [[intro.object]/9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/intro.object#9.sentence-2))

As a consequence it isn't possible to layout the class `C` so that both the direct `A` subobject and the `B` member subobject are allocated at offset 0.

Assuming allocation starts in order with the direct `A` base class subobject at offset 0, then the best possible allocation strategy that also respects alignment requirements is to put the `B` member subobject at offset 4 which is the alignment requirement of both `int` and `B`. Consequently the total size will be at least 8.

Technically I think it would also be permitted by the standard (ignoring the issue raised at the end of this question) to layout the `B` member subobject at offset `0` and the `A` member subobject at any offset other than `0`, because the `A` base class subobject is a *subobject of zero size* that may overlap with part of the `int` subobject. I think there is also no ordering requirement that enforces the base class subobject to have an address comparing smaller-or-equal to that of the `B` member subobject. With that choice the `sizeof(C) == 4` would be possible. But that would be a surprising layout.

So far about the requirements imposed on layout by the standard, but the actual specific layout that the compiler will choose is not specified by the standard. Instead it would be determined by the C++-ABI in use, which is the [Itanium C++ ABI](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html) if you are compiling with GCC or Clang on a Linux system. The allocation algorithm used by this ABI is specified [here](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#class-types) (for classes that aren't POD for the purpose of layout, which `C` isn't). You can see the special case in there:

> Place D at this offset unless doing so would result in two components (direct or indirect) of the same type having the same offset. [...]

MSVC, following its own C++-ABI instead, says `sizeof(C) == 4` and by my tests seems to give both the direct `A` base class subobject as well as the `B` member subobject offset `0`, using a different allocation strategy that doesn't conform to the above requirements.

---

Unfortunately there is a defect in the standard that makes it impossible to correctly layout `C`.

On the one hand as shown above, `B` must be placed at an offset from the direct `A` base subobject, however according to the current definition in the standard `C` is a *standard-layout class*, which implies per [[basic.compound]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic#compound-4) that both the direct `A` base class subobject as well as the `B` member subobject as first non-static member of `C` must be placed at the same address as the `C` object, i.e. at offset 0.

This is a defect in the standard that (I guess) will probably be resolved by making it so that `C` is not standard-layout. Then MSCV's ABI would remain non-conforming, which however also might make adopting that resolution to the defect difficult.

See open [CWG issue 2736](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2736).

Comment: "It is also required that the direct A base class subobject is allocated at offset 0, because C is a standard-layout class." I cannot find this requirement in the standard, can you provide a reference?

Comment: I still have a question that I haven't understood. Class A has neither any member variables nor any methods, so there are no read or write operations on objects of class A. If that's the case, why do we need to ensure that two sub-objects of class A are located at different address in class C?This seems to have no meaning or purpose other than causing C class to have an additional, useless 4-byte storage

Comment: It looks like @Sam Varshavchik's response can answer my question.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI The `C` object is pointer-interconvertible with the base class subobject because `C` is standard-layout. This implies same addresses, i.e. offset 0. See https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#4 (specifically bullet 4.3)

Comment: @leihu As the other answer demonstrates, that would make it impossible to distinguish pointers to the two objects from one another, which isn't desirable.

Comment: @user17732522 Could you please provide the source of this statement "The standard requires that these two objects, because they have the same type and overlapping lifetime, do not have the same address." in the C++ standard? Thank you very much.

Comment: @leihu [\[intro.object\]/9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/intro.object#9.sentence-2)

Comment: @user17732522: One can simplify the example by eliminating `B` and having `class C2 : A { A a; };`  Now it's clear (when C2 is standard-layout) that pointer-interconvertibility applies from C2 to both C2::A and C2::a.  However, C2 is not standard-layout: https://eel.is/c++draft/class.prop#3.7

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes, and similarly the original `C` shouldn't be standard-layout either. But the rules in [class.prop]/3.7 do not exclude this situation.

Answer (score 4):

If there were no padding, then the following assertion would be true (ignoring that the class member is private, which is not relevant):

```
C c;

A *a1=&c;
A *a2=&c.a;

static_assert(a1 == a2);
```

There are two distinct `A` objects, yet their pointers would be the same if there were no padding. This is un-possible.