# What reasons cause a class C, which inherits from class A and has only one member variable of type B, not to be a standard-layout class?

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, standard-layout

The definitions of three classes are as follows:

> ```
> class A { };
>
> class B { A a; };
>
> class C : public A { B b; };
> ```

According to the definition of a standard-layout class in C++11:

1. has no non-static data members of type non-standard-layout class (or array of such types) or reference
2. has no virtual functions (10.3) and no virtual base classes (10.1),
3. has the same access control (Clause 11) for all non-static data members,
4. has no non-standard-layout base classes,
5. either has no non-static data members in the most derived class and at most one base class with non-static data members, or has no base classes with non-static data members, and
6. has no base classes of the same type as the first non-static data member

Classes A and B are clearly standard-layout classes. The issue arises with class C, which doesn't appear to violate any of the standard-layout class definitions, yet it is still defined as a non-standard-layout class. Does class C violate any specific rule?

I used the Clang compiler for testing.

Comment: GCC says standard-layout, MSVC and Clang say not: https://godbolt.org/z/1M9M5j8Yc

Comment: I believe it's a defect. The footnote for bullet 6 says "This ensures that two subobjects that have the same class type and that belong to the same most derived object are not
allocated at the same address" - but it doesn't actually ensure that; this is exactly what happens in your example. For this reason, the definition in C++17 is more elaborate, and in particular looks at the members of the type of the first data member (and at their members, recursively).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik It is certainly a defect. There is a normative equivalent of that note in [intro.object] that conflicts with the standard-layout definition when taken together with the rules for pointer-interconvertibility requiring same addresses. It is [CWG 2736](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2736). I guess the question is here why the compilers decide to resolve this conflict one way or the other, in particular when the rules for standard-layout types (even if conflicting with something else) are pretty clearly written.

Comment: It might have something to do with different interpretations of `6`. That `C` is an `A` and the first data member is also kind of an `A` (First member in `B`).

Comment: This appears to duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77075989/why-does-class-c-which-only-contains-member-variables-of-type-b-have-sizeofc . Please clarify.

Comment: @ecatmur I think these should be two different questions. While the issue you mentioned also involves standard layout, it primarily discusses memory layout issues. This question, on the other hand, is about determining whether a class is a standard layout class based on the C++11 standard. Additionally, the two questions involve different types of class B: one inherits from A, and the other does not inherit from A but includes a member variable of type A.

Comment: I believe @IgorTandetnik's explanation is correct.